# What is the name of this chart, and is there an online tool to create one?

Tags: data-visualization

I would like to create a chart like the one on the left [here](http://www.cdec-decoder.org/concepts/alignment.html) in order to visualize maximum probabilities:

[image]

Is there a name for this type of chart, and is there a tool to create a similar one with my own data?

Comment: [This](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/C/C96/C96-2141.pdf) paper just calls it 'word alignment' (see fig 1 & 2), though it adds lines joining the pairs, while [this](http://www.statmt.org/wmt08/pdf/WMT03.pdf) calls it an 'alignment matrix' (see the discussion under Figure 1), which makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one on the left is a heatmap with discrete color scheme. As a bonus the one on the right is rotated [slopegraph](http://charliepark.org/slopegraphs/).

Heatmap examples in R (with [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/)): [Quick Heatmap Plotting](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/)